# Uploading files in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

What would be the best practice to upload files in MongoDB. I recently came accross Multer. It's easy to use, but it uploads files in the file system instead of uploading directly into the MongoDB.

Comment: I would never have files stored in mongodb, rather store the files in S3 and have the urls in mongodb

Comment: you should use gridfs https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multer is a high-level wrapper for Busboy and unfortunately doesn't callback with a [`Stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) unless you're writing a [`StorageEngine`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/StorageEngine.md) for it. The reason you want a stream so badly is because otherwise you would have to buffer the whole file in-memory of your Node process before being able to do anything with it. Streams are much more efficient and allows you to stream the data somewhere meanwhile you're receiving it, only buffering in-memory in case you cannot pipe the data somewhere at equal rate as you're receiving it.

Combining a custom `StorageEngine` with [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream) would allow you to write the data to GridFS in real-time as you receive the data (e.g the user is still uploading).

I've found two GridFS Storage Engines for Multer:
https://github.com/ISMAELMARTINEZ/gridfs-storage-engine
https://github.com/arjandepooter/multer-gridfs
The latter doesn't seem to have any docs but it's still easy to use just looking through the source.

Comment: I just wrote one and is pretty well documented and tested. https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage